# mariadb slow to response due to high query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have a g7 server that use as database server
and i installed window server 2016 and maria db version 10.1.39-MariaDB on it

my hardware have 2 CPU  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz and 64 gig of ram and 4*128 gig hp ssd 6gbps raid 10

but when my load is going up to 1000 query per second it slow down and crashed..
all my tables are innodb and i have 500-600 mil record and db size is about 40-50 gig

my config is

```
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 512M
innodb_file_per_table=1
max_connection=4000

table_open_cache = 1536
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256k
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 256
query_cache_size = 64M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 12

max_allowed_packet=16M

innodb_io_capacity = 2000
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 64

#innodb_dedicated_server = true

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 48G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 24
```

which of my config is wrong and how can i get the best performance!?

update:when database stoped ram usage is 4-5 gig and when database in load ram go up to 40-45 gig,also my used my connection is about 3500 connection..

Comment: How much *free* RAM do you have (when MariaDB is not running)? Randomly looking at some of your system variables: [thread_concurrency](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#thread_concurrency): this was deprecated in MariaDB 5.5. [innodb_io_capacity](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_io_capacity): This seems much too high, the default it 200. `max_connection`: It's actually called [max_connections](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_connections) (plural). 4000 sounds very high - this can eat up a lot of RAM, I think. (I'm no expert ...)

Comment: @dbdemon : max_connections does not eat any RAM. It does not reserve any memory. Even if you create 4000 connections, MariaDB/Windows is using threadpool by default, and a memory cost of connection, if it is idle, is around 20-30K, making the total cost for all connections (if they are idle) , some 100M. If the connections are not idle, there will be some threads (number of threads usually much less than number of connections), and a thread needs a stack which is around 300K. All in all this is tiny.

Comment: @peiman : If you got a crash, there is a bug. Your config has nothing to do with the bug, it is not supposed to crash. You can file a bug in MariaDB's JIRA, but I'd suggest to use a later version of MariaDB,  which not as ancient as 10.1. 10.1 will not live for very long time (Oct 2020 is EOL). 10.4, something like that might be more appropriate.

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub no maria db dont crash,it just slow, my app crashed due to low response from database.i will update the subject..

Comment: @dbdemon i updated my question.

Comment: @dbdemon - With SSDs, `innodb_io_capacity` can/should be much higher than the default.

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub - each thread takes some space, so a too-large `max_connections` will chew up RAM.  However, his machine is quite large.  Still 4000 is much too high.

Comment: So, not really a "crash".

Comment: @peimanF. - "slow" and "high query" -- These cannot be fixed via configuration.  Find the slow query and show it to use, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  The solution may be as simple as a composite index or a reformulation of the query.

Comment: @RickJames thank you, you mean my configuration dont have any thing to improve? i cant change `innodb_io_capacity` or `innodb_read_io_threads` or `innodb_thread_concurrency` or `innodb_write_io_threads` ?

Comment: @peimanF. - Decreasing `max_connections` _may_ prevent swamping the server.  Increasing the various "capacity settings _may_ improve I/O since you have SSDs.  But, seriously, the best fix to sluggish MySQL is to work on the queries.  1000qps is not very fast; 10K is probably feasible with your hardware and configuration.

Comment: @RickJames : Imagine a say, some Java App server , several of them, each having a connection pool, all pointing to the same database server. They never use all connections concurrently. So the connections are idle. All  "too high" comments refer to situations where all connections are busy all the time. If connection is doing nothing, the cost is 20-30K THD structure plus whatever prepared statement may add to memory use plus, "SHOW PROCESSLIST" will take a bit longer and show a bit more. That's it.

Comment: It is a thread pool, since the DBMS is using MariaDB's/Windows default pool-of-threads for thread_handling, so you ony have as many physical threads is only involved if threads_running is 4000, if all connections are busy at the same time. And this can be prevented by setting thread_pool_max_threads to much lesser value. e.g 500, which iirc is even default in 10.1

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links. From SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; for your server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3500 -- is that Max_used_connections? If so, that is *terrible*. Imagine 3500 people, each with a grocery cart, in a grocery store. Imagine them trying to move through the aisles to pick up food items. It is a mess; essentially it is too crowded for anyone to get anything done. The same thing happens with MySQL/MariaDB.  In this case it is mutexes, and other things.

Put another way, each process gets 2/3500 of the CPU time.  That is, practically none.  So, each connection takes really long to get anything *finished*.

So, the cure is to find the slow queries and speed them up.  See:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

(Use `long_query_time=1` so you can catch some of the shorter, but frequent, queries.)

Comment: ssd hards dont affect slow queries? i mean when i use sata have more slow queries then i use ssd ?

Comment: @peimanF. - A "slow query" is defined as taking more than X seconds of _elapsed_ time.  SATA is slower than SSD, so that adds to the _elapsed_ time.  Hence SATA will exhibit more "slow queries".  Almost always, improving the slowest, say, 5 queries (SATA or SSD, whatever) will help the system significantly.  Then "rinse and repeat" until satisfied.  One big query that scans a many GB (SATA or SSD), if eliminated or drastically changed, _may_ lead to all other queries seeming to go faster.

Comment: @peimanF. Try the free version of JetProfiler.com for a quick way to identify slow queries.  JP calls them Top Queries and this low impact software will also identify Top Tables to be scrutinized.